# Unable to find input field in selenium because the page is dynamic and changes values when updated

Tags: html, python-3.x, selenium, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I can't find input field with selenium because the page is dynamic and values changes when page is updated here is an example:

```html
<jn-form-typeahead-occupations _ngcontent-ciw-c201="" placeholder="Fx byggeri, transport" label="Stilling eller arbejdsområde" _nghost-ciw-c169=""><div _ngcontent-ciw-c169="" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid"><label _ngcontent-ciw-c169="" class="block full-width margin-bottom-quart required" for="19b3-71ca">Stilling eller arbejdsområde</label><jn-typeahead-reactive-occupations _ngcontent-ciw-c169="" class="block full-width ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid" _nghost-ciw-c168=""><input _ngcontent-ciw-c168="" autocomplete="off" type="text" class="block full-width" id="19b3-71ca" placeholder="Fx byggeri, transport"><!----></jn-typeahead-reactive-occupations><jn-form-control-validator _ngcontent-ciw-c169="" class="block full-width margin-top-half" _nghost-ciw-c154=""><!----></jn-form-control-validator></div></jn-form-typeahead-occupations>
```

When updated:

```html
<jn-form-typeahead-occupations _ngcontent-asn-c201="" placeholder="Fx byggeri, transport" label="Stilling eller arbejdsområde" _nghost-asn-c169=""><div _ngcontent-asn-c169="" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid"><label _ngcontent-asn-c169="" class="block full-width margin-bottom-quart required" for="83da-33ab">Stilling eller arbejdsområde</label><jn-typeahead-reactive-occupations _ngcontent-asn-c169="" class="block full-width ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid" _nghost-asn-c168=""><input _ngcontent-asn-c168="" autocomplete="off" type="text" class="block full-width" id="83da-33ab" placeholder="Fx byggeri, transport"><!----></jn-typeahead-reactive-occupations><jn-form-control-validator _ngcontent-asn-c169="" class="block full-width margin-top-half" _nghost-asn-c154=""><!----></jn-form-control-validator></div></jn-form-typeahead-occupations>
```

I have noticed that 'c168' is unique and that 'jn-typeahead-reactive-occupations' is unique but I don't know how to select the input field and send it keys.
Here is a few examples of some of the things I have tried:
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[contains(text(), 'c168')]").send.keys('hello')

browser.find_element_by_xpath("[contains('c168')]/input").send.keys('hello')

browser.find_element_by_tag_name("jn-typeahead-reactive-occupations" and css_selector("input")).send.keys('hello')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution that works, I just copied the whole xpath with the chrome development tool:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[6]/jn-root/jn-layout-main/section/main/article/jn-jobseeking-detail/jn-page/jn-form/form/jn-job/jn-details-container/div/fieldset/div/div[1]/jn-form-typeahead-occupations/div/jn-typeahead-reactive-occupations/input").send_keys('hello')
```

I hope this is usefull for someone else

Comment: Wouldnt this be enough '//jn-form-typeahead-occupations/div/jn-typeahead-reactive-occupations/input' ?

Answer (score 1):

1. The page structure may change, e.g. some extra 'div' is addded or 'div' is changed to 'span', etc.
2. It's easier to ready shorter ones.

You should use shorter locators, e.g. like this:

```
//*[label(text() = 'Stilling eller arbejdsområde')]/input
```

It means "Find a web element with label 'Position or work area' and take it's input.

Comment: Your XPath expression need to be fixed with : `//label[.="Stilling eller arbejdsområde"]/following::input[1]` Since the text contains special characters, I think we should be cautious if we use this method to locate the element.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @Sergii Dmytrenko, you should use relative XPath expressions. If you need something to locate the input element, you can use the following one (3 predicates) :

```
//input[@class="block full-width"][@autocomplete="off"][@type="text"]
```

Look for an input element which fullfill 3 attributes conditions (`@class`,`@autocomplete`,`@type`).

If you need to strengthen it, you can add the "c168" condition.

```
//input[@class="block full-width"][@autocomplete="off"][@type="text"][contains(name(@*[1]),"c168") or contains(name(@*[2]),"c168") or contains(name(@*[3]),"c168") or contains(name(@*[4]),"c168")or contains(name(@*[5]),"c168") or contains(name(@*[6]),"c168")]
```

Or to follow your first idea :

```
//jn-typeahead-reactive-occupations[contains(name(@*[1]),"c168") or contains(name(@*[2]),"c168") or contains(name(@*[3]),"c168") or contains(name(@*[4]),"c168")or contains(name(@*[5]),"c168") or contains(name(@*[6]),"c168")]/input
```